# Value tips for parallelism parameter in dbms_mview.refresh

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

I've got eight materialized views with each containing about a thousand rows. They are refreshed with `force on demand` in a very time critical job which runs every minute. While refreshing, the views need to deliver data.

I'd want to use the following command for refreshing:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_mview.refresh(list => 'MVIEW1, MVIEW2, [...]',
                     atomic_refresh => TRUE);
END;
```

Now there exists the `parallelism` parameter. I thought, it would be cool and clever to set an intelligent and well rethought value for it.

Are there general generally accepted tips for values for this parameter? Should it be equal to the number of materialized views (while keeping sane limitations)?

Thanks for help.

Comment: use a parallel hint in the underlying SQL itself (for example select /*+ parallel (tab, 8) */ from my_table tab, ...).  Your driving table (alias if used) should be specified here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering the parallelism parameter, as with any parallel operations in Oracle, you should really consider the number of CPUs and the available I/O capacity.  Also consider, can you afford to consume all available CPU, or do you need to leave some capacity for other users.

Also, note that even if you set the parallelism parameter, parallelism won't kick in, unless the materialized view was created as parallel.

There's a nice little whitepaper on the subject here:
http://www.doug.org/newsletter/march/MV_Refresh_Parallel.pdf

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll consider your tips. I thought the `parallelism` parameter determines how many processes are used to refresh the materialized views - for example 3 mviews and `parallelism=3`, so every mview is refreshed in one process (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96568/rarmviea.htm#94135 Definition of the parameter parallelism). My guess is that this has nothing to do with the mview being created as parallel in the first place. Please correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Comment: Did you read the whitepaper?  If the view was not created as parallel, or not altered to parallel after creation, then specifying parallelism will not do anything.  The parallelism hint, if specified, and if a given MV is parallel enabled, will spawn parallel execution processes to refresh the MV in parallel.  It does not determine how many MVs are concurrently built.  A single execution of DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH refreshes one MV at a time.  Each individual MV may be refreshed in parallel, with multiple parallel execution slaves.  Hope that's clear.

Comment: Ok, I studied the whitepaper again thoroughly. Unfortunately I access multiple tables via database links which I do not have direct access to, so I can't alter them for parallel execution. Thanks again for your efforts.